# Создание таблицы SQLite нажатием кнопки

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Добрый день. Подскажите, каким образом можно создать таблицу методом onClick? Например я создаю школьное расписание, и при первом входе в приложение создается база данных `timetable.bd` а при нажатии кнопки "Создать расписание" создается `TABLE_NAME` с именем `Calendar.getInstance().getTime();` и в нее уже добавляю уроки, время, темы и т.д. Отдельные таблицы нужны для привязки к календарю (дате). Все мои попытки закончились провалом. Прошу объяснить в теории. Или подскажите где почитать (посмотреть примеры).

Comment: базы данных не так работают. Если вам нужна новая таблица в процессе работы с БД - вы неправильно спроектировали БД. Структура таблиц всегда статична, динамичны только поля этих таблиц. Советую почитать по дисциплине СУБД, прежде чем браться за работу и тем более настаивать, что вам это надо, потому что то, что вы пытаетесь сделать - лютый треш (здесь более уместно другое слово, которое нельзя писать на публичных ресурсах). В любом случае, ваша затея так и будет заканчиваться провалом. Почитать можно (непременно нужно) например, Л. Бейли "Изучаем SQL", как самое доступное на эту тему

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что не стоит при первом входе создавать базу (может поля? Или в крайнем случае таблицу).

База уже должна быть заранее создана. А при нажатии кнопки - подключаться к ней.

По простому - есть база, в ней 5-6 таблиц (занятия на каждый день недели + суббота) [id | lesson | time (тут можно либо тип datestamp, либо varchar, если будете тулить время отрезками).

Пользователь открывает аппликацию, в методе onCreate выполняется подключение к БД и выгрузка данных на ваше Активити (в ListView, наверное).

Реализуется либо PHP+mySQL, либо (проще) FireBase.

Comment: Дело в том, что таблицы нужны каждый день разные (например расписание меняется каждую неделю), и старые таблицы должны оставаться в сохранности а не перезаписываться каждую неделю. Плюс возможность посмотреть, что у меня было в этот день в феврале (да и вообще для ведения статистики и подсчета учебных часов, например, отдельного урока). Думаю, Вы уловили лейтмотив - таблицы стерать нельзя.